# Dynamic dropdown not working properly in ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

You can change here also ->https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-djze7u

home.html

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-content *ngFor="let item of users">
      <ion-row>
        <ion-label>{{item.name}}:</ion-label>
        <ion-label>{{item.age}}</ion-label>
```

> Here is the loop which I want to show value into dropdown according to item.term

```
         <ion-select [(ngModel)]="check[item.age]">
          <ion-option value="0" selected>0</ion-option>
          <ion-option *ngFor="let v of caldrop(item.term)" value="{{v}}">
            {{v}}
          </ion-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

Home.ts

```
export class HomePage {
```

> according to this term vale dropdown will show from 0 to this term value

```
 users:any = [
    { name: 'Composite Factory', age: 1, term:2 },
    { name: 'Todd', age: 2, term:1 },
    { name: 'Lisa', age: 3, term:4 }
  ];
  check:any = [];
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
  }
  caldrop(myval:any){
    console.log(myval)
    let myarr:any = [];
    for(let i=1;i<=myval;i++){
      myarr.push(i);
    }
    return myarr;
  }
}
```

Comment: your stackblitz seems to be erroring out with "Cannot assign to a reference or variable!" atm

Comment: Please replace this line <ion-select [(ngModel)]="item"> with  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="check[item.age]"> into home.html

Comment: here is the updated url https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-4ie4jk you had also forgotton to set `check:any[]=[]` in home.ts

Comment: here all values are selected I want to show this value into dropdown user will select this value.

Comment: what should check[age] initially be?

Comment: I am trying to make this line dynamic by this way but if you have any other way you can choose it this is the main problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158850/discussion-between-somnath-and-suraj-rao).